# solidity ^0.5.0 factory pattern mapping apprach

Tags: solidity

new to solidity.

Trying to understand the better approach for using a `mapping` storage in factory contract.

2 options:

1. Use `mapping(address => Contract[])`
2. Use `mapping(address => address[])`

Sample factory:

```
contract CampaignFactory {

    mapping(address => Campaign[]) campaigns;

    function createCampaign(uint min_contrib) public {
        Campaign newCampaign = new Campaign(min_contrib, msg.sender);
        campaigns[msg.sender].push(newCampaign);
    }

    function getCampaignsByAddress(address creator) public view returns (Campaign[] memory) {
        return campaigns[creator];
    }
}
```

As i understand, the first option suppose to use more storage space to store the whole contract instance.
However, for both options `createCampaign` cost (remix estimation) is the same +- `660000` gas. 
Additionally, `getCampaignsByAddress` with the return type `Campaign[]` strangely returns only addresses instead of full instances (so i suppose **only the address is stored**).

Question: what difference does it make to use option #1 or #2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no difference except that you'll get more type checking help from the Solidity compiler if you use `Campaign[]`.

In both cases, as you noted, the only thing stored is an address. Using the `address` type just means the compiler can't help you if you accidentally try to store a non-`Campaign` in your array.

So my advice is to use `Campaign[]`.